# Deserializing XML in Android using X-Stream

Tags: java, android, xstream

*SOLVED*
Changed Contents contents to:

```
// Lists
    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "Contents")
    public List<Contents> Contents = new ArrayList<Contents>();
```

I'm trying to deserialize the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Items>
   <Item>
      <type>Test</type>
      <uid>1</uid>
      <depends>1</depends>
      <catid>1</catid>
      <label>Test</label>
      <defaultVal>default</defaultVal>
      <answer>Test</answer>
      <Contents>
         <Content>
            <uid>1</uid>
            <label>Test</label>
         </Content>
      </Contents>
   </Item>
</Items>
```

The problem is that when I reach Contents it crashes due to going deeper by another level.

This is how i DeSerialize my XML, it works without the contents.

```
public static Object DeSerializeFromXML(String xml, Class items, Class item)
{
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.processAnnotations(new Class[] { items, item });

    return xstream.fromXML(xml);
}
```

Here's how I call the DeSerialize method:

```
Items reader = (Items)Data.Serialization.Instance().DeSerializeFromXML(xml, Items.class, Item.class);
```

And as last my Objects:

Items.cs

```
@XStreamAlias("Items")
public class Items
{
    public Items() { items = new ArrayList<Item>(); }

    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "Item")
    public List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
}
```

Item.cs

```
@XStreamAlias("Item")
public class Item
{
    // Type
    public String type = "";

    // Ids
    public int uid = 0;
    public int catid = 0;
    public int depends = 0;

    // Values
    public String label = "";
    public String defaultVal = "";
    public String answer = "";

    // Lists
    public Contents content;    

    public Item()
    {
    }

    public Item(String type, int uid, int catid, int depends, String label,
            String defaultval, String answer)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.catid = catid;
        this.depends = depends;
        this.label = label;
        this.defaultVal = defaultval;
        this.answer = answer;

        content = new Contents();
    }

    @XStreamAlias("Contents")
    public static class Contents
    {
        public Contents()
        {
            contents = new ArrayList<Content>();
        }

        @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "Content")
        public List<Content> contents = new ArrayList<Content>();
    }
```

Content.cs

```
@XStreamAlias("Content")
public class Content
{
    public int uid = 0;
    public String label = "";

    public Content()
    {
    }

    public Content(int uid, String label)
    {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.label = label;
    }
```

I'm not quite sure if my annotations for the next level are correct.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should really post your crash log.

Comment: Solved it by changing Contents to a list and adding the XStream marshall to it.

Comment: If its solved, please post your solution as an answer and *accept* it (see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing Contents to a list and adding the XStream marshall to it.

```
@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "Contents")
public List<Contents> Contents = new ArrayList<Contents>();
```